# SettingWithCopyWarning reason in code snippet

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When processing some medical training data to train a classifier for different medical tests, I got the SettingWithCopyWarning from pandas. I already read about it and figured out it comes from chained indexing a DataFrame, however I can't figure out the point in my code below where I use chained indexing.

```
#Turn the 12 measurement result rows of each patient into one single row for each patient
#the different test results are named: result, result_1, ... , result_11 (for each result)
#the pid and age column is kept only once while all other column fields of the 12 measurement rows are concatenated
#into one single row, also the time field exists now 12 times per row

imputed_features.sort_values(by=['pid','Time'], inplace=True)
sorted_features = train_features.sort_values(by=['pid','Time'])
measurements = []
columns = []
for i in range(12):
    measurements.append(imputed_features.groupby(['pid'], as_index=False).nth(i))
    measurements[i].reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    if( i == 0 ):
        columns = [i for i in measurements[i].columns]
    else:
        measurements[i].drop(['pid', 'Age'], axis=1, inplace=True)
        for j in measurements[i].columns:
            columns.append(f'{j}_{i}')

#the resulting aggregated_features DataFrame
aggregated_features = pd.concat(measurements[0:12], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
aggregated_features.columns = columns
aggregated_features.to_csv('aggregated_features.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you're specifying a row.

`pd.concat(measurements, ....)`

If you still get a warning, maybe copying and merging the 'measurements' will improve it?

`measures = measurements.copy()
pd.concat(measures[0:12], ...)`